# Reuse object's apply functions in Scala

Tags: scala, apply, code-reuse

I have a class A and factory functions using apply method.

```
object A {
  def apply(a:String) {... new A}
  def apply(a:Int) {... new A}
  ...
}

class A(...) {
...
}
```

When I have a subclass B from A with the same factory methods. I have the same apply methods that generates B.

```
object B {
  def apply(a:String) {... new B} // duplication
  def apply(a:Int) {... new B} // duplication 
  ...
}

class B(...) extends A {
...
}
```

Can I reuse the apply methods from A in B?

Comment: is the signature of the constructors of classes A and B the same?

Comment: @Edurardo: It's almost the same except that one parameter is missing in B, as A sets the parameter to true.

Comment: how will you discriminate when you need an `A` or a `B` instance?

Comment: @maasg: apply in object works as an object factory, so you can call A(..) or B(..) whatever necessary.

Comment: yes, requiring you to duplicate the code, which is what you want to avoid. I was thinking in terms of `object FooFactory` that could create A or B instances depending on some criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to define a mixin trait that contains the common methods, which will depend on an abstract factory function. Then, the companion objects can extends such mixin, only implementing the specific way to create the corresponding instance.

An example:

```
trait FooFactory[T] {
    def make(s:String, i:Int): T
    def apply(s:String):T = make(s, 0)
    def apply(i:Int):T = make("", i) 
}

class A(s:String = "", i:Int = 0) {
  def foo:String = s+i
  override def toString() :String = s"[$foo]"
}

// object A {
//   def apply(a:String): A = { new A(s=a)}
//   def apply(a:Int): A = { new A(i=a)}
// }

object A extends FooFactory[A] {
    def make(s:String, i:Int) = new A(s,i)
}

class B(s:String = "") extends A(s,-1){
  override def foo:String = s+":"+super.foo
}

// object B {
//   def apply(a:String):B = { new B(a)}
//   def apply(a:Int):B = { new B(a.toString)}
// }

object B extends FooFactory[B] {
    def make(s:String, i:Int) = new B(s)
}
```

If you need access to specific methods of the target class hierarchy, you  can constrain the type to that class of its subtypes.

```
trait FooFactory[T <: A] {
    def make(s:String, i:Int): T
    def apply(s:String): T = make(s, 0).someAMethod()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just added what was needed for my solution. You can edit or delete it if you don't like it.

Comment: @prosseek that's unusual, but I like the collaborative approach. I just adapted it to my usual style.